# How can I modify files in a jffs2 image

Tags: firmware

I'm working with the firmware of SIP phone. I extracted the JFFS2 file system image from the firmware and mounted it using modprobe ike this:

```
sudo modprobe mtdram total_size=36360
sudo modprobe mtdblock 
sudo modprobe jffs2
sudo modprobe block2mtd
sudo dd if=~/1C6A83.jffs2  of=/dev/mtdblock0
sudo mount -t jffs2 /dev/mtdblock0 ~/mnt
```

However when I try to change files on the mounted device I get an error "No space left on device". What am I doing wrong? May be my device mtdblock0 is protected from writing?

Comment: Try to `mount -o rw` and access the files using root user. If that doesn't work, immediately after the mount command look at the last lines of the kernel message log (`tail /var/log/messages` or `dmesg | tail`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

`cp: cannot create regular file '/home/main/fs/voip/logo.png': No space left on device`

Comment: Here are my actions step by step
`$ sudo modprobe -v mtdram total_size=36360
$ sudo modprobe -v mtdblock 
$ sudo modprobe -v jffs2
$ sudo modprobe -v block2mtd
$ sudo dd if=~/st.extracted/1C6A83.jffs2  of=/dev/mtdblock0
72718+1 records in
72718+1 records out
37232064 bytes (37 MB, 36 MiB) copied, 1,09873 s, 33,9 MB/s
$ sudo mount -o rw -t jffs2 /dev/mtdblock0 ~/fs`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing, and did not get the *no space left on device* (I read somewhere that that error may be because of an incomplete image...), but I could not figure out how to update the image. `md5sum` of the original file did not change, and running `sync` as suggested after googling was unsuccessful as well...

I went the way of extracting the jffs2 image and then repacking the jffs2 file system.
I put everything [on github](https://github.com/JoSSte/Foscam-FI9826W), but here is the essence:

This will unpack a `.jffs2` file system to `/my/target/dir` and repack to `mtd_root.sum.bin`

### Unpacking

```
mount -t jffs2 -o ro /tmp/mtdblock0 /tmp/e2jffs2
(cd /tmp/e2jffs2; tar cf - .) | (cd "/my/target/dir" ; tar xpf -)
umount /tmp/e2jffs2
```

### Repacking

```
mount -t jffs2 -o ro /tmp/mtdblock0 /tmp/e2jffs2
mkfs.jffs2 --root=/tmp/e2jffs2/ --output=/tmp/mtd_root.bin --eraseblock=128KiB --pad --no-cleanmarkers
sumtool  --pad --eraseblock=128KiB --input=/tmp/mtd_root.bin --output=$(dirname "/my/target/dir")/mtd_root.sum.bin
```